# How to properly implement pointer event tracking

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, gesture, pointer-events

I want to implement a gesture using the pointer events api.

To get started I tried to store all `pointerId`'s that are active on an element into an array.
To accomplish that, I have registered a `pointerdown` event listener on the element and a `pointerup` listener on the whole document, so that, if a pointer is dragged off the element, while active, it still un-registers from the array, when the pointer is lifted of the surface of the device, etc.

Below is an example that shows what I am trying to accomplish:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target')

var activePointers = [];

target.addEventListener('pointerdown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();

  // Add the pointerId to the array.
  activePointers.push(event.pointerId);
  target.textContent = activePointers;
});

// I realize that this document-wide listener should only be added once the 
// pointer is down, but that would add needless complexity to the example.
document.addEventListener('pointerup', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();

  // Remove the pointerId from the array.
  activePointers = activePointers.filter(item => item !== event.pointerId);
  target.textContent = activePointers;
});
```

```css
#target {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background: tomato;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- pointer events polyfill for mobile safari and firefox. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/pep/0.4.3/pep.js"></script>

<div id="target" touch-action="none"></div>
```

As you can see, the element displays the ID's of the pointers that were placed on it. When a pointer is lifted of the surface of the device, its ID should disappear.

There are multiple problems here which I do not know how to fix properly.

- `pointerup` does not always fire, causing inactive ID's to build up in the array.
- When a pointer is moved around a bit, it behaves as-if it was removed from the surface, causing `pointerup` to be fired. This cannot be circumvented with `preventDefault()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()`.
- When touching the screen with multiple pointers, a context menu can open, even though `preventDefault()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()` were called on the event.
- When moving a pointer on the element, a scroll can be started, even though `preventDefault()` was called on the event.

How do I implement this properly, without the above issues?

*EDIT0:* Added polyfill for safari and firefox mobile.
*EDIT1:* Image example of multiple pointers still registered even though no pointer is placed on the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jby3f.png
*EDIT2:* It behaves as expected on iOS-Safari using the polyfill.
*EDIT3:* It behaves as expected on Android-Chrome.

Comment: "*As you can see, the element displays the ID's of the pointers that were placed on it*". I don't see IDs at all.

Comment: @RobG you have to click / touch the element to have the IDs appear.  
Some of the issues (IDs not un-registering / context-menu showing) only appear when multiple pointers are used.

Comment: Safari (and others) doesn't support the [*PointerEvent* interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @RobG I have tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge. The numbers appear in all of them.  
I have also tested it with Safari on an iPhone, where it does not work.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a browser–specific issue, I can't get Chrome 71 or Firefox 65 to show multiple IDs (Chrome shows the number 1, Firefox 0).

Comment: @RobG, I have added a polyfill for safari and firefox mobile, as-well as the `touch-action="none"` attribute, which makes this work on safari.
I have a touch-screen on my laptop, where I was able to test the above issues.

Comment: @RobG, The issues from above arise when the element is touched with multiple fingers on a desktop device. https://i.imgur.com/ggnSBNv.png